# !checkfileexists does not exist in the current context SQLite - c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I've been using SQLite for an application that I was writing and when I created a class, everytime I used !checkfileexists, it was always incorrect. Am I missing a using namespace or a reference? Here's the code:

```
public async Task<bool> onCreate(string databasePath)
{
    try
    {
        if (!CheckFileExists(databasePath).Result)
        {
            using (databaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply: `if (CheckFileExists(databasePath))`

Answer (score 0):

The function `CheckFileExists` is in `System.Windows.Forms`, thus not acsessable in a Windows Phone 8.1 project. The System.IO.File.Exists method is also not available.

You can write your own `CheckFileExists` function.

```
public async Task<bool> onCreate(string databasePath)
{
    try
    {
        if (!await CheckFileExists(databaseName))
        {
            using (databaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection(databaseName))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string filename)
{
    bool exists = true;
    try
    {
         Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         exists = false;
    }
    return exists;
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with this, but your code suggests that you want to create a database and never use it again.

*Some notes:*

The only folder (and sub folders) you may access freely is the `Current Local Folder`.

You need to get permission from the user if you want to use any other directory, this can be done using a Folder Picker, or in the Appmanifest editing the capabilities to get Music and Pictures folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`CheckFileExists` can be written as File.Exists using `System.IO. CheckFileExists` doesn't seem to be an object in any namespace I'm aware of. You might have to create a Task for `CheckFileExists` and add any missing code.